# RabbitMQ - allow only one process per user

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, sharding

To keep it short, here is a simplified situation:

I need to implement a queue for background processing of imported data files. I want to dedicate a number of consumers for this specific task (let's say 10) so that multiple users can be processed at in parallel. At the same time, to avoid problems with concurrent data writes, I need to make sure that no one user is processed in multiple consumers at the same time, basically all files of a single user should be processed sequentially.

Current solution (but it does not feel right):

- Have 1 queue where all import tasks are published (`file_queue_main`)
- Have 10 queues for file processing (`file_processing_n`)
- Have 1 result queue (`file_results_queue`)
- Have a manager process (in this case in `node.js`) which consumes messages from file_queue_main one by one and decides to which `file_processing` queue to distribute that message. Basically keeps track of in which `file_processing` queues the current user is being processed.

Here is a little animation of my current solution and expected behaviour:
[image]

Is RabbitMQ even the tool for the job? For some reason, it feels like some sort of an anti-pattern. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Since you wish to serialize the files for every user , you need to have user specific queues . The consumers can then be spawned based on the load and traffic conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I understand, this also means, that there will be a consumer per user? How can I limit the consumer count to 10 while also making sure that some random 10 users won't fill up the queue making other users wait forever? In my solution, messages are processed in the order they came in, but if there is a queue per user, then when a user sarts processing, he will be able to add files indefinetly as long as the consumer is already up.

Comment: I think Kafka might be a cleaner solution. You can bypass all the coordination and complexity of the competing workers pattern. With Kafka to achieve parallelism and increase throughput you just need to add more brokers to the Kafka topic, that's it!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you create ten queues (and ten consumers) and then distribute users with routing key equal to `user_id mod 10` when you publish them to the exchange. Then you can be certain that the the same user always goes to the same queue. Ie user 120 goes to queue_0, 121 to queue_1... user 123451 to queue_1 etc?

Comment: The goal is to effectively use all 10 consumers. If I distribute the messages by a simple `mod 10`, then there is a big chance that some of the consumers will be idle.

Comment: @Arthur sure, but on average and over time your consumers should have equal load using this approach. This assumes your user-ids are distributed fairly, if not, then hash them first and then use `mod` on the hash or something.

Comment: @MartinWickman the user id's are distributed equally (I've tried distributing them by the last id digit). However, activity between users vary greatly. For example, there are users who barely upload any files and at the same time there are users that can upload thousands of files per month.

Comment: @Arthur I see. I'm reaching a bit here, but if you know which users are heavy users then perhaps partition users that way as well, ie create separate queues for normal users and heavy users. Or, of course, create one temporary queue for each user.

Comment: @MartinWickman, that's already starting to sound more complicated and less effective than trying to manage equal distribution for all users based on the availability of the consumers :D

Comment: @Arthur just want to know.. if u got a solution..? how did u implemented finally..?

Comment: @the_mahasagar I've decided to get rid of `RabbitMQ` entirely for this solution and use only `Redis`. With `RabbitMQ` I would need `Redis` to store additional information about the jobs anyway so I decided to use `Redis`, a couple of `LUA` scripts for atomicity and a `BLPOP` to retrieve jobs. That way I don't need a manager process, consumers will request jobs themselves and it can be easily scaled.

Comment: How about locking and polling (some kind of mutex)?

Comment: @AbhigyanTiwari locking what and where exactly? I suppose a better solution would be separate queues, with a Redis list as a source of truth for which queues should be processed next.

Comment: @Arthur, in my case I had to implement one task only per feature. So I went with Redis as lock store. I set a key with "nx" I guess, returns if it was created or existing. So I retried my task at random interval (time greater than task execution time) if lock was present. Similary we could do for other use cases, maybe yours. I'm unsure. (Lock was per user, "user_id:feature_name:lock" as key).

Comment: @AbhigyanTiwari That's a bit of a different use-case. Also, at a large scale, it's not really sustainable.

Comment: @Arthur, I got the solution for my use case from Redis' website only as here: https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/distributed-locks/  Maybe for your case its matter of tracking multiple keys.

Answer (score 0):

The part about this that doesn't "feel right" to me is the manager process.  It has to know the current state of each consumer, and it also has to stop and wait if all processors are working on other users. Ideally, you'd prefer to keep each process ignorant of the others.  You're also getting very little benefit out of your processing queues, which are only used when a processor is already working on a message from the same user.

Ultimately, the best solution here is going to depend on exactly what your expected usage is and how likely it is that the next message is from a user that is already being processed.  If you're expecting most of your messages coming in at any one time to be from 10 users or fewer, what you have might be fine.  If you're expecting to be processing messages from many different users with only the occasional duplicate, your processing queues are going to be empty much of the time and you've created a lot of unnecessary complexity.

Other things you could do here:

- Have all consumers pull from the same queue and use some sort of distributed locking to prevent collisions.  If a consumer gets a message from a user that's already being worked on, requeue it and move on.
- Set up your queue routing so that messages from the same user will always go to the same consumer.  The downside is that if you don't spread the traffic out evenly, you could have some consumers backed up while others sit idle.

Also, if you're getting a lot of messages in from the same user at once that must be processed sequentially, I would question if they should be separate messages at all.  Why not send a single message with a list of things to be processed?  Much of the benefit of event queues comes from being able to treat each event as a discrete item that can be processed individually.

Comment: The main goal is to effectively use all 10 consumers. If I route messages by a pattern, there is a big chance that most of the consumers will be idling and not used. There is no way to predict how much or how big the files will be from each user. Basically, I want to create a queue for each user that will do some kind of heavy work.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has a unique ID, or the file being worked on has a unique ID then hash the ID to get the processing queue to enter. That way you will always have the same user / file task queued on the same processing queue.

I am not sure how this will affect queue length for the processing queues.

Comment: That's what I am trying to avoid. There is no way to predict how active the user will be. So I need to be able to assign any user to the first available consumer.